# How to set Tableview Cell Movable with option (Share,Done,Delete) Button ? and it's Action ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

> I Want Set Movable Tableview Cell with Button Action.And how can i manage button action.
>
> How Can i implement this stuff.
>
> Here i have Attached image i want like this Image.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: use https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

Comment: but How to use this Library ? @Himanshu

Comment: Is that it? What have you tried? Where's your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it withoutUsing any third party control, using `UITableViewRowAction` of default `UITableView`..

**Below is the code snippet...**

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewRowAction *editAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@" Edit " handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
        // maybe show an action sheet with more options
        //        [self callBlockUser];

    }];
    editAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDestructive title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
        // maybe show an action sheet with more options
        //        [self callBlockUser];


    }];
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return @[deleteAction,editAction];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but In your method only one delete button is coming i want three option that how can i manage ?

Comment: @SanandiyaVipul you can add by new action as `UITableViewRowAction` and return it in the method as `@[deleteAction,editAction,newAction]`